# Clases con stores

Tags: javascript, svelte

En mi proyecto de svelte tengo una clase que tiene stores como parámetros internos, el problema me viene que no se como sacarlos.

Solo he podido sacar uno de ellos con el método `subscribe`

```
<script>
    import { classStore } from "./classStore.js"
    let value = "";
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        classStore.parse("history")
    }
</script>

<h1>ClassStore Demo</h1>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Add history
</button>

{#each $classStore as h}
<p>{h}</p>
{/each}

<!--
{#each classStore.$getData2 as h}
<p>{h}</p>
{/each}
-->
```

```js
class ClassStore {
  constructor() {
    this._data1 = writable([])
        this._data2 = writable([])
  }

  parse(string) {
    this._data1.update(v => [...v, string])
        this._data2.update(v => [...v, string])
  }
    
    subscribe(run) {
        return this._data1.subscribe(run);
    }
    
    getData2(run) {
        return this._data2.subscribe(run);
    }
}

export const classStore = new ClassStore();
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/737188841b4f44e5b2945858ef7bd80c?version=3.42.6

Comment: ¿A _sacar_ te referís a _imprimir_?

Comment: Fíjate en el bucle comentado me da error ya que no tengo acceso al store. realmente no importa que se imprima o no. Exactamente quiero obtener el contenido de _data2

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste agregar `{@debug $classStore}` a tu código? Para ver qué sucede con el Array.